# Resolving a promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I want to use async / await to run  `console.log('Procccess Ends');` after `updateGuider` function resolves..

Something like the code below:

```js
tutor();

async function tutor(){
console.log('tutor function initiated..');
// wait until updateGuider function resolves
await updateGuider('default');
// The expected result is to reach this line after updateGuider resolves, but we can't so far!
console.log('Procccess Ends');


}

function updateGuider(state){    
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 

    if(state == 'done'){
       console.log('updateGuider has been resolved!');
       resolve();    
    }

    switch(state) {
          case 'default':
          speak();
          break;         
    }
    
    });  
}


async function speak(){
  
   setTimeout(function(){
      //after 5 seconds we resolve the updateGuider from speak function
      updateGuider('done')      
   },5000)
  
}
```

But even though we resolve the `updateGuider` it won't run the `console.log('Procccess Ends');`

What I miss and how to fix this?

How can I resolve `updateGuider` from `speak`?

**UPDATE:**  Thanks to [@h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo) This code works but I can't understand how it works could you please give me a hand if it's a good solution and how it works!

```js
tutor();

async function tutor(){
console.log('tutor function initiated..');
// wait until updateGuider function resolves
await updateGuider('default');
// The expected result is to reach this line after updateGuider resolves, but we can't so far!
console.log('Procccess Ends');


}

function updateGuider(state){    
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 

    switch(state) {
          case 'default':
          speak(resolve);
          break;         
    }
    
    });  
}


async function speak(resolve){
  
   setTimeout(function(){
      //after 5 seconds we resolve the updateGuider from speak function
     console.log('entered speak')
     resolve();      
   },5000)
  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is happening in this code--do you think that calling `speak` and calling `updateGuider` *again* will resolve the original returned promise or something?

Comment: That's what I thought!  How can I resolve `updateGuider` from `speak` ???

Comment: Pass it the resolve function?

Comment: Please explain it a bit... pass what?

Comment: Your issue is that when you can `updateGuider('done')` in your timeout you're creating a new promise (and not, like you may think, updating the old one). This can be solved by using `speak(resolve)` inside of your `updateGuider` function, change it to `function speak(resolve)` and call `resolve()` instead of `updateGuider('done')`. That way your original promise will be resolved.

Comment: The resolve function. But that's likely not what you really want to do. If all you're doing is trying to create a 5 second delay you don't need any of the `updateGuider` stuff.

Comment: I think you need to clarify more what do you want exactly, what do you mean by resolve updateGuider from speak, you are calling updateGuider() inside tutor() and when you call it again that's another promise that you are using, you can call speak() in tuto() if you want to but then you have to wrap it in another promise to wait for 5s

Comment: @h2ooooooo can you please provide an answer...

Comment: guys all the example code above is a simplified version of the main code and the timeout is just for debugging..

Comment: Please have a look at my question's update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returning different promises each time you call updateGuider. Strictly speaking, you cannot resolve updaterGuide like this. Also unless you await something in an async function it does nothing, so speak has currently no reason to be async. This is not perfect, but you get the gist of the problem.

```
function updateGuider(state){    
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 

    if(state == 'done'){
       console.log('updateGuider has been resolved!');
       resolve();    
    }

    switch(state) {
          case 'default':
          speak(resolve);
          break;         
    }

    });  
}

function speak(resolve){

   setTimeout(function(){
      //after 5 seconds we resolve the updateGuider from speak function
      resolve()    
   },5000)

}
```

Comment: well you see, every time you call updateGuider you return a NEW PROMISE. let me emphasize on that NEW keyword :) thus, if you dont call it inside speak, but you pass along the first promise's resolve method, you can control it.

So to be exact:

1stPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...}) 
2ndPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...}) 
these 2 resolve methods are different. but inside any Promises body, you can pass along the reference to its own resolve method, and call it any time you want. Thats what you do when you call speak(resolve)